# Tmux - How can I run node app forever after detaching tmux.?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, tmux

I am making my first app in node js and i uploaded it on server. I have a terminal where I am running a session containing two panes, one for running `mongod` and second for running `node app.js` . Now both of them run as long as I keep it running. But how can we make sure after quitting the window it keeps running both of them `mongod`  and  `node`. I am using `tmux`, `mongodb`, `express` and `node`.

I tried `tmux detach` and `tmux attach`. They work. But for `tmux detach` first i have to quit the current command by `ctrl + c` and then i would be able to run `tmux detach`. Am I doing something wrong? Please Help

Comment: Try using the node process manager pm2 - http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: use `<Control-B>d` to detach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume this is for a development environment and not production. In production, keeping something running "forever" makes using a process supervisor to make sure it is restarted when it crashes.

In development, you can use `<Prefix>-d` to detach without cancelling the current command. The Prefix for Tmux is `Control-B` by default.

Comment: OK, then you should be using a process manager like `systemd` or `pm2`, the details of running Node.js apps with `systemd` or `pm2` are well-covered elsewhere.  The app will end up running in the background.

Comment: this will keep running for node js app.js what about mongo ?

Comment: i have a server in which mongo and node both are installed. my database is also placed on the same server. now i can run both of them using tmux. but as you said to run node app.js i need pm2 what about mongo then ? @mark

Comment: You didn't mention what OS or version you are using. MongoDB packages tend to install it so that it is managed by the init systemd-- automatically started at boot, automatically restarted and shutdown at when the server stops. On many Linux distributions is now done with `systemd`.  Tmux is not tool to manage services in production. Tmux is used to let developers keep tools running on a service that they may disconnect and re-conect to. Typically text editors, chat programs and other development tools.  If my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept.

Comment: one last thing, i get it what you said, tmux is used basically for development purpose not for production. for production we have to use systemd or pm2. Now my production is on linux server, and on my server both node and mongo are installed. Actually this was my question, anyways, now do i have to setup mongo on some other place like mongo atlas or azure, or is it possible we can run them both from the same platform ? Thanks plz shed some light

Comment: You can run Node.s and MongoDB on the same server, but if the service is important you way to run twin Node instances on redundant servers, with a load balancer in front and 2 or 3 MongoDB instances in a cluster each on their own server. This way, any server can go down for planned maintenance or unplanned failure while over the overall service keeps running.If you are just starting out at the very beginning, it's a good time to consider PostgreSQL instead. ;) If my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept.